Unable to send data via UDP from android + gstreamer
Pipeline:
gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location = big_buck_bunny_720p_20mb.mp4 ! decodebin ! x264enc ! rtph264pay ! udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000
Above pipeline is working perfectly via Ubantu terminal.
However, I want to acheive through android.
Below is my code:
static void
**run_gstreamer_pipeline(JNIEnv * env, jobject thiz, jstring filepath)** {    
    gst_init(NULL, NULL);    g_print ("Gstreamer initialization complete\n");    
    struct GstreamerStream stream;    stream.pipeline = gst_pipeline_new("pipeline_elem");    
    stream.filesrc = gst_element_factory_make("filesrc", "filesrc_elem");    
    stream.capsfilter = gst_element_factory_make("capsfilter", "capsfilter_elem");    
    stream.decodebin = gst_element_factory_make("qtdemux", "decodebin_elem");    
    stream.x264enc = gst_element_factory_make("x264enc", "x264enc_elem");    
    stream.rtph264pay = gst_element_factory_make("rtph264pay", "rtph264pay_elem");    
    stream.udpsink1 = gst_element_factory_make("udpsink", "udpsink_element");    

    if (!stream.pipeline || !stream.filesrc || !stream.capsfilter || !stream.decodebin || !stream.x264enc || !stream.rtph264pay || !stream.udpsink1) {        
        g_error("Element creation error\n");    
    }    
    
    const char *cStr = (*env)->GetStringUTFChars(env, filepath, NULL);    

    if (cStr == NULL) {        
        // Out of memory error       
        g_print ("Conversion failed\n");    
    }    

    g_object_set(stream.filesrc, "location", cStr, NULL);    
    //g_object_set(stream.x264enc, "bitrate", 1000, NULL);    
    g_object_set(stream.rtph264pay, "pt", 96,NULL);    
    g_object_set(stream.udpsink1, "host", "192.168.1.116", "port", 1234, NULL);    
    gst_bin_add_many(GST_BIN(stream.pipeline), stream.filesrc, stream.decodebin, stream.x264enc, stream.rtph264pay, stream.udpsink1, NULL);    
    
    GstCaps *newCaps = gst_caps_new_simple("video/x-raw","width", G_TYPE_INT, 1920,"height", G_TYPE_INT, 1080, "framerate", GST_TYPE_FRACTION, 60, 1, NULL);  

    g_object_set(stream.capsfilter, "caps", newCaps, NULL);    gst_caps_unref(newCaps);    
    
    if (!gst_element_link_many(stream.filesrc,   stream.decodebin, NULL)) {        
        g_error("Failed to link elements\n");        
        gst_object_unref(stream.pipeline);   
    }    

    if (!gst_element_link_many(stream.x264enc, stream.rtph264pay, stream.udpsink1,NULL)) {        
        g_print("Link Failed\n");        
        gst_object_unref(stream.pipeline);   
    }   
    // g_signal_connect(stream.decodebin, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK(pad_added_handler), &stream);    
    stream.bus = gst_pipeline_get_bus(GST_PIPELINE(stream.pipeline));    
    guint bus_watch_id = gst_bus_add_watch(stream.bus, my_bus_callback, NULL);    
    gst_object_unref(stream.bus);    stream.loop = g_main_loop_new(NULL, FALSE);    
    gst_element_set_state(stream.pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);    
    g_main_loop_run(stream.loop);    
    gst_element_set_state(stream.pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);    
    gst_object_unref(stream.pipeline);    
    g_source_remove(bus_watch_id);    
    g_main_loop_unref(stream.loop);
}

static void 
**pad_added_handler (GstElement *src, GstPad *new_pad, gpointer user_data)** {    
    struct GstreamerStream *data = (struct GstreamerStream *)user_data;    
    GstPad *sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(data->x264enc, "sink");    
    GstPadLinkReturn ret;    GstCaps *new_pad_caps = NULL;   
    GstStructure *new_pad_struct = NULL;    
    const gchar *new_pad_type = NULL;    
    
    g_print("Received new pad '%s' from '%s':\n", GST_PAD_NAME (new_pad), GST_ELEMENT_NAME (src));/* If our converter is already linked, we have nothing to do here */
    if (gst_pad_is_linked(sink_pad)) {        
        g_print("We are already linked. Ignoring.\n");        
        goto exit;    
    }
    /* Check the new pad's type */  
    new_pad_caps = gst_pad_get_current_caps(new_pad);    
    new_pad_struct = gst_caps_get_structure(new_pad_caps, 0);    
    new_pad_type = gst_structure_get_name(new_pad_struct);    
    if (g_str_has_prefix(new_pad_type, "video/x-raw")) {        
        ret = gst_pad_link(new_pad, sink_pad);    
    } else {        
        g_print("It has type '%s' which is not raw audio. Ignoring.\n", new_pad_type);        
        goto exit;    
    }    if (GST_PAD_LINK_FAILED (ret)) {        
        g_print("Type is '%s' but link failed.\n", new_pad_type);   
    } else { 
        g_print("Link succeeded (type '%s').\n", new_pad_type); 
    }    
    
    exit:/* Unreference the new pad's caps, if we got them */
    if (new_pad_caps != NULL)    
        gst_caps_unref(new_pad_caps);
        /* Unreference the sink pad */    
    gst_object_unref(sink_pad);
}

**static gboolean my_bus_callback(GstBus *bus, GstMessage *message, gpointer data)** {    
    g_print("Got %s message\n", GST_MESSAGE_TYPE_NAME(message));    
    
    switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE(message)) {        
        case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR: {            
            GError *err;            
            gchar *debug;            
            gst_message_parse_error(message, &err, &debug);           
            g_print("Error=======: %s\n", err->message);            
            g_error_free(err);            g_free(debug);            
            g_main_loop_quit((GMainLoop *)data);            
            break;        
            }        
        case GST_MESSAGE_ASYNC_DONE: {            
            g_print("Async Done\n");            
            break;        
            }        
        case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:            
            g_print("EOSDone\n");            
            g_main_loop_quit((GMainLoop *)data);            
            break;        
        default:            
            break;   
            }    
    return TRUE;
}

Error logs:
024-12-15 22:05:42.216  6800-6800  Compatibil...geReporter org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  Compat change id reported: 210923482; UID 10334; state: ENABLED
2024-12-15 22:05:42.265  6800-6800  System.out              org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  Video path is /data/user/0/org.freedesktop.gstreamer.streamer.stream/files/bb2.mp4
2024-12-15 22:05:42.265  6800-6800  GLib+stdout             org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  Gstreamer initialization complete
2024-12-15 22:05:42.267  6800-6800  GLib+stdout             org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  Got state-changed message
2024-12-15 22:05:42.267  6800-6800  GLib+stdout             org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  Got state-changed message
2024-12-15 22:05:42.267  6800-6800  GLib+stdout             org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  Got state-changed message
....
2024-12-15 22:05:42.274  6800-6834  CCodec                  org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  state->set(ALLOCATING)
2024-12-15 22:05:42.274  6800-6834  CCodec                  org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  allocate(c2.android.aac.decoder)
2024-12-15 22:05:42.276  6800-6834  Codec2Client            org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  Available Codec2 services: "default" "default0" "software"
2024-12-15 22:05:42.277  6800-6834  CCodec                  org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  setting up 'default' as default (vendor) store
2024-12-15 22:05:42.282  6800-6834  CCodec                  org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  Created component [c2.android.aac.decoder]
2024-12-15 22:05:42.282  6800-6834  CCodec                  org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  [c2.android.aac.decoder] state->set(ALLOCATED)
2024-12-15 22:05:42.282  6800-6834  CCodecConfig            org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  read media type: audio/mp4a-latm
2024-12-15 22:05:42.284  6800-6834  ReflectedParamUpdater   org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  extent() != 1 for single value type: algo.buffers.max-count.values
2024-12-15 22:05:42.284  6800-6834  ReflectedParamUpdater   org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  extent() != 1 for single value type: output.subscribed-indices.values
2024-12-15 22:05:42.284  6800-6834  ReflectedParamUpdater   org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  extent() != 1 for single value type: input.buffers.allocator-ids.values
2024-12-15 22:05:42.284  6800-6834  ReflectedParamUpdater   org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  extent() != 1 for single value type: output.buffers.allocator-ids.values
2024-12-15 22:05:42.284  6800-6834  ReflectedParamUpdater   org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  extent() != 1 for single value type: algo.buffers.allocator-ids.values
2024-12-15 22:05:42.284  6800-6834  ReflectedParamUpdater   org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  extent() != 1 for single value type: output.buffers.pool-ids.values
2024-12-15 22:05:42.284  6800-6834  ReflectedParamUpdater   org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  extent() != 1 for single value type: algo.buffers.pool-ids.values
2024-12-15 22:05:42.286  6800-6834  CCodecConfig            org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  query failed after returning 20 values (BAD_INDEX)
2024-12-15 22:05:42.286  6800-6834  CCodecConfig            org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  c2 config diff is Dict {
c2::u32 coded.aac-packaging.value = 0
c2::u32 coded.bitrate.value = 64000
c2::u32 coded.pl.level = 0
c2::u32 coded.pl.profile = 8192
c2::i32 coding.drc.album-mode.value = 0
c2::float coding.drc.attenuation-factor.value = 1
c2::float coding.drc.boost-factor.value = 1
c2::i32 coding.drc.compression-mode.value = 3
c2::i32 coding.drc.effect-type.value = 3
c2::float coding.drc.encoded-level.value = 0.25
c2::float coding.drc.reference-level.value = -16
c2::u32 input.buffers.max-size.value = 8192
c2::u32 input.delay.value = 0
string input.media-type.value = "audio/mp4a-latm"
c2::u32 output.delay.value = 2
c2::float output.drc.output-loudness.value = 0.25
string output.media-type.value = "audio/raw"
c2::u32 raw.channel-count.value = 1
c2::u32 raw.channel-mask.value = 0
c2::u32 raw.max-channel-count.value = 8
c2::u32 raw.sample-rate.value = 44100
}
2024-12-15 22:05:42.287  6800-6800  GLib+stdout             org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  Got state-changed message
2024-12-15 22:05:42.287  6800-6800  GLib+stdout             org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  Got state-changed message
2024-12-15 22:05:42.287  6800-6834  MediaCodec              org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  flushMediametrics
2024-12-15 22:05:42.287  6800-6834  CCodec                  org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  [c2.android.aac.decoder] buffers are bound to CCodec for this session
2024-12-15 22:05:42.287  6800-6834  CCodec                  org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  appPid(6800) width(0) height(0)
2024-12-15 22:05:42.288  6800-6834  CCodecConfig            org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  no c2 equivalents for flags
2024-12-15 22:05:42.288  6800-6834  CCodecConfig            org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  c2 config diff is   c2::u32 raw.channel-count.value = 6
c2::u32 raw.sample-rate.value = 48000
2024-12-15 22:05:42.288  6800-6834  Codec2Client            org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  W  query -- param skipped: index = 1107298332.
2024-12-15 22:05:42.288  6800-6834  CCodec                  org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  encoding statistics level = 0
2024-12-15 22:05:42.288  6800-6834  CCodecConfig            org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  query failed after returning 20 values (BAD_INDEX)
2024-12-15 22:05:42.289  6800-6834  CCodec                  org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  [c2.android.aac.decoder] state->set(STARTING)
2024-12-15 22:05:42.289  6800-6834  Codec2Client            org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  W  query -- param skipped: index = 1342179345.
2024-12-15 22:05:42.289  6800-6834  Codec2Client            org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  W  query -- param skipped: index = 2415921170.
2024-12-15 22:05:42.290  6800-6834  Codec2Client            org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  W  query -- param skipped: index = 1610614798.
2024-12-15 22:05:42.290  6800-6834  C2Store                 org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  debug.c2.use_dmabufheaps set, forcing DMABUF Heaps
2024-12-15 22:05:42.290  6800-6834  C2Store                 org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  Using DMABUF Heaps
2024-12-15 22:05:42.290  6800-6834  CCodecBufferChannel     org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  [c2.android.aac.decoder#443] Created input block pool with allocatorID 16 => poolID 17 - OK (0)
2024-12-15 22:05:42.291  6800-6834  CCodecBufferChannel     org...org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  allocate(c2.qti.avc.decoder)
2024-12-15 22:05:42.297  6800-6842  CCodec                  org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  setting up 'default' as default (vendor) store
2024-12-15 22:05:42.299  6800-6842  CCodec                  org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  Created component [c2.qti.avc.decoder]
2024-12-15 22:05:42.299  6800-6842  CCodec                  org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  [c2.qti.avc.decoder] state->set(ALLOCATED)
2024-12-15 22:05:42.300  6800-6842  CCodecConfig            org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  read media type: video/avc
2024-12-15 22:05:42.300  6800-6834  CCodecConfig            org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  c2 config diff is   c2::u32 raw.channel-mask.value = 252
2024-12-15 22:05:42.300  6800-6834  CCodecBuffers           org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  [c2.android.aac.decoder#443:Output[N]] popFromStashAndRegister: at 0us, output format changed to AMessage(what = 0x00000000) = {
2024-12-15 22:05:42.301  6800-6842  ReflectedParamUpdater   org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  extent() != 1 for single value type: output.buffers.pool-ids.values
2024-12-15 22:05:42.304  6800-6842  ReflectedParamUpdater   org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  extent() != 1 for single value type: vendor.qti-ext-dec-info-misr.misr_info_first_field.misr_dpb_luma
2024-12-15 22:05:42.304  6800-6842  ReflectedParamUpdater   org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  extent() != 1 for single value type: vendor.qti-ext-dec-info-misr.misr_info_first_field.misr_dpb_chroma
2024-12-15 22:05:42.304  6800-6842  ReflectedParamUpdater
org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  extent() != 1 for single value type: vendor.qti-ext-dec-info-misr.misr_info_second_field.misr_opb_chroma
2024-12-15 22:05:42.306  6800-6842  CCodecConfig            org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  ignoring local param raw.size (0xd2001800) as it is already supported
2024-12-15 22:05:42.306  6800-6842  CCodecConfig            org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  ignoring local param default.color (0x5200180b) as it is already supported
2024-12-15 22:05:42.306  6800-6842  CCodecConfig            org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  ignoring local param raw.hdr-static-info (0xd200180a) as it is already supported
2024-12-15 22:05:42.306  6800-6842  CCodecConfig            org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  query failed after returning 17 values (BAD_INDEX)
2024-12-15 22:05:42.306  6800-6842  CCodecConfig
2024-12-15 22:05:42.306  6800-6842  ColorUtils              org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  W  expected specified color aspects (0:0:255:255)
2024-12-15 22:05:42.307  6800-6800  GLib+stdout             org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  Got state-changed message
2024-12-15 22:05:42.308  6800-6800  GLib+stdout             org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  Got state-changed message
2024-12-15 22:05:42.308  6800-6832  GStreamer+video-info    org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  W  0:00:00.350452500 0xb400007134e5eb00 ../gst-libs/gst/video/video-info.c:766:gst_video_info_to_caps invalid matrix 0 for RGB format, using RGB
2024-12-15 22:05:42.308  6800-6800  GLib+stdout             org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  Got need-context message
2024-12-15 22:05:42.308  6800-6800  GLib+stdout             org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  Got have-context message
2024-12-15 22:05:42.309  6800-6800  GLib+stdout             org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  Got need-context message
2024-12-15 22:05:42.309  6800-6832  GStreamer+amcvideodec   org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  E  0:00:00.351254635 0xb400007134e5eb00 ../sys/androidmedia/gstamcvideodec.c:1987:gst_amc_video_dec_set_format: Codec only supports GL output but downstream does not
2024-12-15 22:05:42.309  6800-6832  GStreamer+videodecoder  org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  W  0:00:00.351277916 0xb400007134e5eb00 ../gst-libs/gst/video/gstvideodecoder.c:928:gst_video_decoder_setcaps: Subclass refused caps
2024-12-15 22:05:42.309  6800-6832  GStreamer+decodebin     org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  W  0:00:00.351290312 0xb400007134e5eb00 ../gst/playback/gstdecodebin2.c:2586:connect_pad:<decodebin_elem> Couldn't set amcvideodec-omxqcomvideodecoderavc0 to PAUSED
2024-12-15 22:05:42.309  6800-6841  CCodec                  org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  [c2.qti.avc.decoder] state->set(RELEASING)
2024-12-15 22:05:42.309  6800-6846  CCodec                  org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  W  release order: surface --> comp
2024-12-15 22:05:42.309  6800-6846  CCodec                  org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  [c2.qti.avc.decoder] state->set(RELEASED)
2024-12-15 22:05:42.309  6800-6841  MediaCodec              org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  Codec shutdown complete
2024-12-15 22:05:42.309  6800-6842  hw-BpHwBinder           org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  onLastStrongRef automatically unlinking death recipients
2024-12-15 22:05:42.310  6800-6832  MediaCodec              org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  flushMediametrics
2024-12-15 22:05:42.311  6800-6847  CCodec                  org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  state->set(ALLOCATING)
2024-12-15 22:05:42.311  6800-6848  CCodec                  org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  allocate(c2.qti.avc.decoder.low_latency)
2024-12-15 22:05:42.313  6800-6848  CCodec                  org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  setting up 'default' as default (vendor) store
2024-12-15 22:05:42.315  6800-6848  CCodec                  org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  Created component [c2.qti.avc.decoder.low_latency]
2024-12-15 22:05:42.315  6800-6848  CCodec                  org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  [c2.qti.avc.decoder.low_latency] state->set(ALLOCATED)
2024-12-15 22:05:42.315  6800-6848  CCodecConfig            org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  read media type: video/avc
2024-12-15 22:05:42.319  6800-6848  ReflectedParamUpdater   org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  extent() != 1 for single value type: vendor.qti-ext-dec-info-misr.misr_info_first_field.misr_dpb_luma
2024-12-15 22:05:42.319  6800-6848  ReflectedParamUpdater   org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  extent() != 1 for single value type: vendor.qti-ext-dec-info-misr.misr_info_first_field.misr_dpb_chroma
2024-12-15 22:05:42.319  6800-6848  ReflectedParamUpdater   org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  extent() != 1 for single value type: vendor.qti-ext-dec-info-misr.misr_info_first_field.misr_opb_luma
2024-12-15 22:05:42.319  6800-6848  ReflectedParamUpdater   org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  extent() != 1 for single value type: vendor.qti-ext-dec-info-misr.misr_info_first_field.misr_opb_chroma
2024-12-15 22:05:42.319  6800-6848  ReflectedParamUpdater   org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  extent() != 1 for single value type: vendor.qti-ext-dec-info-misr.misr_info_second_field.misr_dpb_luma
2024-12-15 22:05:42.319  6800-6848  ReflectedParamUpdater   org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  extent() != 1 for single value type: vendor.qti-ext-dec-info-misr.misr_info_second_field.misr_dpb_chroma
2024-12-15 22:05:42.319  6800-6848  ReflectedParamUpdater   org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  extent() != 1 for single value type: vendor.qti-ext-dec-info-misr.misr_info_second_field.misr_opb_luma
2024-12-15 22:05:42.319  6800-6848  ReflectedParamUpdater   org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  extent() != 1 for single value type: vendor.qti-ext-dec-info-misr.misr_info_second_field.misr_opb_chroma
2024-12-15 22:05:42.320  6800-6848  ReflectedParamUpdater   org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  extent() != 1 for single value type: output.buffers.pool-ids.values
2024-12-15 22:05:42.321  6800-6848  CCodecConfig            org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  ignoring local param raw.size (0xd2001800) as it is already supported
2024-12-15 22:05:42.321  6800-6848  CCodecConfig            org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  ignoring local param default.color (0x5200180b) as it is already supported
2024-12-15 22:05:42.321  6800-6848  CCodecConfig            org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  ignoring local param raw.hdr-static-info (0xd200180a) as it is already supported
2024-12-15 22:05:42.321  6800-6848  CCodecConfig            org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  query failed after returning 18 values (BAD_INDEX)
2024-12-15 22:05:42.321  6800-6848  ColorUtils              org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  W  expected specified color aspects (0:0:255:255)
2024-12-15 22:05:42.322  6800-6800  GLib+stdout             org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  Got state-changed message
2024-12-15 22:05:42.322  6800-6800  GLib+stdout             org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  Got state-changed message
2024-12-15 22:05:42.323  6800-6832  GStreamer+video-info    org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  W  0:00:00.365241197 0xb400007134e5eb00 ../gst-libs/gst/video/video-info.c:766:gst_video_info_to_caps invalid matrix 0 for RGB format, using RGB
2024-12-15 22:05:42.323  6800-6832  GStreamer+amcvideodec   org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  E  0:00:00.365399010 0xb400007134e5eb00 ../sys/androidmedia/gstamcvideodec.c:1987:gst_amc_video_dec_set_format: Codec only supports GL output but downstream does not
2024-12-15 22:05:42.323  6800-6832  GStreamer+videodecoder  org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  W  0:00:00.365426354 0xb400007134e5eb00 ../gst-libs/gst/video/gstvideodecoder.c:928:gst_video_decoder_setcaps: Subclass refused caps
2024-12-15 22:05:42.323  6800-6832  GStreamer+decodebin     org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  W  0:00:00.365438958 0xb400007134e5eb00 ../gst/playback/gstdecodebin2.c:2586:connect_pad:<decodebin_elem> Couldn't set amcvideodec-omxqcomvideodecoderavclowlatency0 to PAUSED
2024-12-15 22:05:42.323  6800-6847  CCodec                  org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  [c2.qti.avc.decoder.low_latency] state->set(RELEASING)
2024-12-15 22:05:42.323  6800-6850  CCodec                  org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  W  release order: surface --> comp
2024-12-15 22:05:42.323  6800-6850  CCodec                  org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  [c2.qti.avc.decoder.low_latency] state->set(RELEASED)
2024-12-15 22:05:42.324  6800-6847  MediaCodec              org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  Codec shutdown complete
2024-12-15 22:05:42.324  6800-6848  hw-BpHwBinder           org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  onLastStrongRef automatically unlinking death recipients
2024-12-15 22:05:42.324  6800-6832  MediaCodec              org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  D  flushMediametrics
2024-12-15 22:05:42.324  6800-6800  GLib+stdout             org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  Got state-changed message
2024-12-15 22:05:42.324  6800-6800  GLib+stdout             org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  Got state-changed message
2024-12-15 22:05:42.328  6800-6800  GLib+stdout             org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  Got latency message
2024-12-15 22:05:42.328  6800-6800  GLib+stdout             org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  Got duration-changed message
2024-12-15 22:05:42.345  6800-6832  GLib+stdout             org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  Received new pad 'src_0' from 'decodebin_elem':
2024-12-15 22:05:42.345  6800-6832  GLib+stdout             org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  Link succeeded (type 'video/x-raw').
2024-12-15 22:05:42.345  6800-6832  GLib+stdout             org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  Received new pad 'src_1' from 'decodebin_elem':
2024-12-15 22:05:42.345  6800-6832  GLib+stdout             org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  We are already linked. Ignoring.
2024-12-15 22:05:42.345  6800-6800  GLib+stdout             org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  I  Got state-changed message
2024-12-15 22:05:42.346  6800-6833  GStreamer+amcaudiodec   org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  E  0:00:00.388669635 0xb400007134e5b8c0 ../sys/androidmedia/gstamcaudiodec.c:1208:gst_amc_audio_dec_handle_frame: Downstream returned not-linked
2024-12-15 22:05:42.346  6800-6833  GStreamer+amcaudiodec   org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  E  0:00:00.388810468 0xb400007134e5b8c0 ../sys/androidmedia/gstamcaudiodec.c:1208:gst_amc_audio_dec_handle_frame: Downstream returned not-linked
2024-12-15 22:05:42.346  6800-6833  GStreamer+amcaudiodec   org...top.gstreamer.streamer.stream  E  0:00:00.388947083 0xb400007134e5b8c0 ../sys/androidmedia/gstamcaudiodec.c:1208:gst_amc_audio_dec_handle_frame: Downstream returned not-linked

The only thing that stands out to me is the error message "gst_amc_video_dec_set_format: Codec only supports GL output but downstream does not "
